# Re-instantiate UITabBarItem with tag

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to re-instantiate a view controllers associated with a `UITabBarItem` with tag `num` each time it is selected. The best solution I could find uses the delegate method `tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:)` but this doesn't use the tag.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to re-instantiate those controllers if you only need to change the tag?

Comment: I don't need to change the tag. I want to re-instantiate the controller by using the tag as a reference. e.g. `reInstantiateVC(withTag: num`)

Comment: What is tag? Selected tab index?

Comment: Tag is the tag used when making a `UITabBarItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `selectedIndex` property of the UITabBarController inside of `tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:)` method.